# Sorting an array of zeros, negative and positive numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array in Java

```
int num[] = {5, -3, 0, -18, 1, 2, 0};
```

I want to make it look like these

```
{-3, -18, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2}
```

What I have right now is this

```
for (int i=0; i<num.length;i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<num.length-1;j++)
        {
            if (num[j]<0)
            {
                temp=num[j];
                c=num[j-1];
                num[j-1]=temp;
                num[j]=c;
            } 
        }  
    }
```

But this sort just negative numbers, and I can't find solution how to sort zeros. 
Can you help me, please?

Comment: I don't understand the sorting logic, could you expand a bit?

Comment: I need to have negative numbers at begging of array, followed by zeros, and the positive numbers at the end.

Comment: @Tunaki turn an unsorted array into another unsorted array...?

Comment: OK, but should there be any sorting rule regarding positive numbers together?

Comment: The reason it is only sorting negatives is because in your loop you are only comparing to 0.

Comment: Yes you're only comparing to zero. You need a boolean to know when to stop and need another test.

Comment: What kind of sorting is this? `5, -3, 0, -18, 1, 2, 0` to `-3, -18, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2`?

Comment: Are you having further issues moving on? If your problem is solved then you should mark the answer that helped resolving the problem as **accepted**. This helps other people who have the same question. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.sort()` with a custom comparator, which will preserve the order of the numbers with equal sign:

```
Integer[] num = {5, -3, 0, -18, 1, 2, 0};
Arrays.sort(num, (a, b) -> Integer.signum(a) - Integer.signum(b));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num)); // [-3, -18, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2]
```

**EDIT:** Since it turns out that OP just wanted an ordinary sort, that would be

```
Arrays.sort(num);
```

Comment: `Integer.signum` might be a better choice.

Comment: plus one lambdas the cleanest approach in my view

Answer (score 4):

The main idea is to have 2 pointers iterating inwards from the head and tail of the `int[]` until they meet, and swap them on the way if a `positive` and `negative` are misplaced. This will work:

```
public class Solution {
    public void sortNumbers(int[] A) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = A.length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length && i <= b; i++) {
            int cur = A[i];
            if (cur < 0) {
                this.swap(A, i, a);
                a++;
            } else if (cur > 0) {
                this.swap(A, i, b);
                b--;
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    private void swap(int[] A, int i, int j) {
        int tmp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

The runtime is O(n), where n is the length of `int[]`

Comment: I think loop termination condition `i < A.length && i <= b;` can be simplified jst as `i <= b`

Answer (score 4):

Time Complexity: O(n) and Space Complexity: O(1)

```
public void sortNumbers(int[] nums) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = nums.length - 1;
    int index = 0;

    while (start < end && index <= end) {
        if (nums[index] < 0) {
            int temp = nums[index];
            nums[index] = nums[start];
            nums[start] = temp;
            start++;
            index++;

        } else if (nums[index] > 0) {
            int temp = nums[index];
            nums[index] = nums[end];
            nums[end] = temp;
            end--;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 D array, sorting it based on each array's first element or second element can be done as follows:

For example, we want to sort
`arr= [[-2147483646,-2147483645],[2147483646,2147483647]]`  based on each arrays second element. We do it like in latest Java 8

`Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[1]));`

This takes care of positive and negative integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple bubble sort, comparing signs of neighboring elements and swapping those who stand wrong (i. e. `i-th` has "bigger sign" than `(i+1)-th`):

```
for (int j = num.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        if (Integer.signum(num[i]) > Integer.signum(num[i+1])) {  // comparing signs
            int temp = num[i];
            num[i] = num[i+1];
            num[i+1] = temp;               
        } 
    }  
}
```

Bubble sort is stable, so "equal" elements (here, equal elements are considered those who have the same sign) never change their order, giving you desired result. Being not very effective, this simple algorithm still helps to understand how sorting method, that doesn't require extra space and operates only on initial array, can be implemented.

Comment: First I misunderstood your question, I've just edited my answer to follow actual requirements

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy implentation using a boolean with a do...while loop and a for inner loop :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num[] = {5, -3, 0, -18, 1, 2, 0};

    int temp = 0;
    boolean finished = false;

    do{
        finished = true; // This will stay true if nothing needs to be changed in your array.
        for (int i = 0 ; i < num.length - 1 ; i++){
            if (num[i] > num[i+1]){
                finished = false; // Can not go off the loop if it is not sorted yet.
                temp = num[i]; // Interchanging of array's indexes
                num[i] = num[i+1];
                num[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    } while(!finished);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
}
```

---

**Output**

```
[-18, -3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: How is this different than using [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[]))?

Comment: @dguay The algorithm my friend. Sort() ain't no fun.

Comment: @dguay `Arrays.sort()` is implemented very differently

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Maybe but `Arrays.sort()` output the same thing. Why the need to implement a new sort algorithm if he simply wants to sort an array? Just like @Cinnam answer...

Answer (score 0):

There are many different sorts which can be used to sort an array of integers from a simple bubble sort to a slightly more complicated heap sort. Some sorts are quicker than each other, for example the heap sort is quicker than the bubble sort, however this mainly affects large arrays. This is due to the amounts of swaps and comparisons between the numbers.

**Bubble Sort**

```
public class BubbleSort 
{
    public void sortArray(int[] a)
    {       
        int c, d, swap;

        for(c = 1; c < a.length; c++)
        {
            for (d = 0; d < a.length - c; d++) 
            {
                if (a[d] > a[d+1])
                {
                    swap = a[d];
                    a[d] = a[d+1];
                    a[d+1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            int correctNumber = i+1;
            System.out.println("Value "+correctNumber+" of the sorted array which was sorted via the Bubble Sort is: "+a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Heap Sort**

```
public class HeapSort 
{
    private static int[] a;
    private static int n;
    private static int left;
    private static int right;
    private static int largest;


    public static void buildheap(int []a)
    {
        n=a.length-1;
        for(int i=n/2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            maxheap(a,i);
        }
    }

    public static void maxheap(int[] a, int i)
    { 
        left=2*i;
        right=2*i+1;
        if(left <= n && a[left] > a[i])
        {
            largest=left;
        }
        else
        {
            largest=i;
        }

        if(right <= n && a[right] > a[largest])
        {
            largest=right;
        }

        if(largest!=i)
        {
            exchange(i,largest);
            maxheap(a, largest);
        }
    }

    public static void exchange(int i, int j)
    {
        int t=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=t; 
    }

    public static void sort(int[] a0)
    {
        a=a0;
        buildheap(a);

        for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
        {
            exchange(0, i);
            n=n-1;
            maxheap(a, 0);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            int correctNumber = i+1;
            System.out.println("Value "+correctNumber+" of the sorted array which was sorted via the Heap Sort is: "+a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```