# How to add a JComponent to a certain index of a Box

Tags: java, swing, layout

In my software, I have a ScrollPane whose view has a Box Layout and holds JPanels.
A button allows to add a JPanel to that Box, and i'd like to find a way to place it in a certain position.

Here is a screenShot:
[image: theApp]

Here is the example code:

```
public class MyClass {

    //run a swing App
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException   {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ScrollPaneExample());        
    }
}


class ScrollPaneExample implements Runnable{

    private Box boxHolder;
    private JPanel scrollPaneContainer;

    //show a JFrame
    @Override
    public void run(){           
        JFrame mainFrame = initFrame();
        mainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //init JFrame and add to it a scrollpane and a button
    private JFrame initFrame() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(initScrollPane(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(initButtonAdd(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return mainFrame;
    }

    //init scrollpane which contains a boxholder for colored panels
    private Component initScrollPane() {
        scrollPaneContainer = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        boxHolder = Box.createVerticalBox(); 
        scrollPaneContainer.add(boxHolder, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        return new JScrollPane(scrollPaneContainer);
    }

    //init a button which add a panel to the boxholder on pressed
    private Component initButtonAdd() {
        JButton button = new JButton("addPanel");
        button.setBackground(Color.green);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               boxHolder.add(createPanel());
               scrollPaneContainer.revalidate();
           }
        });
        return button;
    }

    //create a panel setting its background to a random color
    private Component createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(randomColor());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
           public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                /** TODO code to replace the clicked panel with a new one*/     
           }
           @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
           @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
           @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
           @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        });
        panel.add(new JLabel("a colored Panel"));
        return panel;
    }

    //generate a randomColor
    private Color randomColor() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        float r = rand.nextFloat() / 2f ;
        float g = rand./***/nextFloat() / 2f;
        float b = rand.nextFloat() / 2f;
        Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);
        return randomColor;
    }


}
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
int indexPosition = 2;
boxHolder.add(createPanel(), indexPosition);
```

UPDATE 1-2
First of all: thanks. 
I noticed that the example code provided  does not reflect properly my code, and i have lost the objective while explaining my problem.
I'll keep the previous question as it is since it can be usefull to someone else.
Let's move on.

I need to replace a certain panel, so, what we did before with a given index, should be implemented with someting more dynamic. 
i've added a mouseListener to our Jpanels. On click, they should be replaced by a new panel. Something like:

```
    JPanel replacePanel = createPanel();
   // next istruction leads to a compilation error since Box do not has this method
    int indexOfClickedPanel= boxHolder.indexOf(this);
    boxHolder.add(replacePanel,indexOfClickedPanel);
```

In my code i use a JLabel instead of a button. Its icon changes on mouseEntered/Exited, and add a certains panel onPressed. It sounds to me more appropriate, any suggestion will be appreciated btw.

Comment: Is my answer what you are after or did you mean something else in your question?

Comment: Instead of a `MouseListener`, add an `ActionListener` to your `Button`.

Comment: Dan, thanks for your answer, it does properly what i meant. 
The problem is that it was not my problem, i was asking the wrong thing. I'm gonna edit the question to add the true problem xD

Comment: @Koop4 so would you be able to tell me which panel it is meant to replace when you click on the button (or label or whatever component you use)?

Comment: you're right, let me add some code as example

Comment: Code edited. I've changed the mouseListener with an ActionListener, and added a mouseListener to the panels created by the method createPanel().
It is not implemented (see TODO). It should behave as wrote in the last update.

Comment: @Koop4 Assuming you want to replace the panel when you click on it see edit 2 of my answer

Comment: @Koop4 So have you sorted what you wanted sorting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this answer I add the extra code to your listener but that can easily be changed if you need to change it.

If you would like to add another panel at that position any index position you can use

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    boxHolder.add(createPanel());
    int indexPosition  = 2;
    try //Will only add here if you have a component in index position 1
    {
        boxHolder.add(createPanel(),indexPosition);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
    scrollPaneContainer.revalidate();
}
```

This will add a panel in at index position 2 and move current panel in index position 2 to index position 3.

If you would like to replace the current panel in index position 2 you can use

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    boxHolder.add(createPanel());
    int indexPosition  = 2;
    try //Will only remove it if there is already a panel or other component there
    {
        boxHolder.remove(indexPosition);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
    try //Will only add here if you have a component in index position 1
    {
        boxHolder.add(createPanel(),indexPosition);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
    scrollPaneContainer.revalidate();
}
```

This will remove the panel currently in index position 2 and add another one in its place.

However if you try to add a component to index position 2 without there being any components in index position 0 or 1 you will get the exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position`. Hence that is why the code for adding a panel in which ever index position your int variable, `indexPosition`, states is in a `try catch` block. It is the same reason for the remove method.

**Edit**

As [trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230513/trashgod) said it would be better if you used an `Action Listener` so in your code it would be.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Rest of your code
    }
});
```

**Edit 2**

If you are looking to replace a `JPanel` when you click on the `JPanel` you could do something like this.

```
private Component createPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(randomColor());
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    panel.add(new JLabel("a colored Panel"));
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override 
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int indexPosition  = boxHolder.getComponentZOrder(panel);
            try
            {
                boxHolder.remove(indexPosition);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
            try //Will only add here if you have a component in index position 1
            {
                boxHolder.add(createPanel(),indexPosition);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
            scrollPaneContainer.revalidate();
        }
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    });
    return panel;
}
```

As for suggestions on improvements. I would suggest changing your `initScrollPane` method to the following code so the scrolling is a speed you might be more familiar to.

```
private Component initScrollPane() {
    scrollPaneContainer = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
    boxHolder = Box.createVerticalBox(); 
    scrollPaneContainer.add(boxHolder, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    JScrollPane jSP = new JScrollPane(scrollPaneContainer);
    jSP.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
    return jSP;
}
```

Comment: About Edit 2: getComponentZOrder(panel) method works properly.
Thanks also  for the initScrollPane() reimplementation.

In future i will need to implements comparable for those panels.
And after each Action, i should order them in the scrollPane. Do you think i should take care of something?

Comment: @Koop4 Just read your comment properly. How would you compare your panels?

Comment: I've not been preperly technical. In my software those JPanels contain an object which has a certain int field, and i 'll implement the comparable interface easily. 
Let's say our panels became objects having a random(0-100) int field evaluated in their constructor, and a new button which order them top to bottom (incrementally). 
Do you think this kind of implementation is good to do something like that? 
I'm sure about we can do it, but i m still wondering if using a BoxLayout is the proper way for this kind of management.
Thanks again, and if you need some example code, i ll provide.

Comment: @Koop4 To do something like that you might want to look at [Implementing merge sort in Java 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375648/implementing-merge-sort-in-java-7/34382414#34382414) or [Sorting an array of zeros, negative and positive numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219561/sorting-an-array-of-zeros-negative-and-positive-numbers/34232574#34232574). These show sorts such as the bubble sort and the merge sort. So the best way to do it would be to get your ints from all your JPanels and then sort them. Then rearrange the JPanels based on the sort outcome

Comment: @Koop4 As for using `BoxLayout` it is really a matter of personal preference. For this particular program it seems to work well because of the function `getComponentZOrder`. However if your looking for another layout which might work [`MigLayout`](http://www.miglayout.com/) is one of my favourites